# Adding custom menu items using AppleScript for the application when on the dock

Tags: applescript, contextmenu, menuitem, dock

You can write an AppleScript and save it as an application, and then place it on the dock. But is it possible to add menu items to it so that when secondary clicked it show these menu items? If so, how to define them, and define their actions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug out how I did it. This works for leopard and older: It's a cocoa app wrapper for shell commands. For snow leopard you can do it directly for apple scripts.

1. xcode -> new project... -> Application -> Cocoa Application
2. (right pane) NIB Files -> (right click) Add -> New File -> Cocoa -> Objective C class -> "runScript.m"
3. modify runScript.h (right pane):

```
#import Cocoa/Cocoa.h // add gt and lt (does not show here)
@interface runScript : NSObject {}
-(IBAction)runHello:(id)sender;
@end
```

1. modify runScript.m:

```
#import "runScript.h"
@implementation runScript
-(IBAction)runHello:(id)sender
{
    NSTask *script=[[NSTask alloc] init];
    [script setLaunchPath:@"~/Desktop/hello.app/Contents/MacOS/hello"];
    [script launch];
}
```

1. NIB Files -> MainMenu.xib (doubleclick opens interface builder)
2. interface builder -> tools -> library (objects-page) -> library-cocoa-"objects & controllers" -> Object (drag and drob this blue cube to Main Menu.xib window)
3. select Object (that you just added) -> interface builder -> tools -> identity inspector -> class -> select runScript from drop down (this is the object c class you created in 2)
4. MainMenu.xib -> (double click) MainMenu -> (delete extra + ) rename "file-> new" to file->runHello
5. right click runHello -> drag and drop the circle next to "Actions: runHello" to Run Script -> runHello (in MainMenu.xib)
6. In Mainmenu.xib window: right click "File's owner" -> drag And Drop circle next to dockMenu to MainMenu
7. Go back to xcode -> build -> build and go -> save all

Now the program in dock should have "file->runHello" item when right clicked.

You can delete the window in "Mainmenu.xib". Also NSTask can excecute all shell commands, not just scripts.

In Snow Leopard there is an "applescript IBAction". And you can change "Cocoa Application" to "Applescript application".

br,
Juha

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I *really* appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Applescript. Saving an Applescript as an application really only removes the requirement of needing Script Editor to run the script as well as a couple other minor changes. In the end, it's still just a script. If you need more functionality, then you should look into creating Applescript-based applications with Xcode (in what used to be known as Applescript Studio).

Comment: Well, I thought it might be possible by editing meta data of the app contents. I don't mind doing it with XCode. Any clues on what API calls I should use there?

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode, do the following:

1. NIB-files -> MainMenu.xib (doubleclick). This opens interface builder.
2. file -> new... -> Cocoa -> mainMenu
3. link your mainMenu's dockMenu to "File's owner" (second click mainMenu -> drag and drop the dockMenu-circle to File's owner)
4. double Click mainMenu and edit the item names. Link the item "send actions" to the actions you want to perform (same way as in bullet 3).

Bullet 4 is a bit shaky as I don't remember excatly how it goes. I'll give you a link for further reading: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000036.php. There should not be any problems to link it with applescript, though.

I would appreciate if you could post a working solution (when you get it to work, I mean).

br,
Juha

Comment: just to add: I am using leopard, in snow leopard there is supposed to be the same drag and drop functionality in automator... True or rumors?